# Python library error

Tags: python, anaconda, xlsxwriter

I raised this question previously and because I cannot add images at comments and I don't have an answer yet, revive it seem the only solution...
I start to think that there is an issue with this library, xlsxwriter. I tried to install it on another PC and I got the same result, same error:
[image]
[image].
The module is installed in the same directory as pandas, numpy and other Anaconda's packages which are working properly. I've done everything by the book, it works fine on my laptop but apparently it doesn't on others. I ran the program using both Rodeo and Python shell with same result...Somehow the PC doesn't wanna follow the path to the proper directory like it does with the other libraries. 
I'm sorry for insisting with this but I can't find a solution and can't take my remuneration...
Any help, idea is appreciated. I can't be the only one?!
Thanks

Comment: How did you install it? What command did you write? What was the result of that command? Please, paste the _text of the error_ not a screenshot that doesn't tell us anything useful.

Comment: First from what I see here it should come preinstalled: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs. Anyway because it couldn't find it I used to methods: first with conda in Anaconda cmd and second from Rodeo with ! pip install xlsxwriter

Comment: Yes, it definitely does come installed with anaconda. Can you check which `python` are you running? From a first guess it looks like the path of python you're using is not the anaconda one, do you have multiple python installations?

Comment: It's in the same folder, like I said with the other libraries...I cannot replicate now, because I'm home and it works fine on my laptop...I eddited the image and added another one for more proof

Comment: does the module have a `__init__.py` in it? its own folder?

Comment: I installed the last version of python 2.7

Comment: Josh, I'm not sure what you mean by that but it has it's own folder in Anaconda2/lib...same as pandas and numpy. I couldn't use scipy library either, but that was just for testing...maybe it helps. It appeared that the person had previous instances of Python but neither one was active, they were deleted but I could see them because they weren't deleted with registry cleaner...Could that matter?